# Basic Ruby Programming

Tags: ruby, while-loop, function

I have the following ruby code, from a learning to program book. I understand it ,however it asks me to try and remove the variable good_answer and answer. It says I will have to use return to exit the loop. I am not sure where to start. Any clues would be great, I just want to figure it out.

```
def ask question
  good_answer = false
  while (not good_answer)
    puts question
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase

    if (reply == 'yes' or reply == 'no')
      good_answer = true
      if reply == 'yes'
        answer = true
      else
        answer = false
      end
    else
      puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
    end
  end #while ends here

  answer #This is what we return (true of false)
end

puts 
ask('Do you like eating Cheese?')
ask('Are you crazy?')
rain = ask 'Do you like rain?'

puts rain
```

Comment: Why are you trying to cheat when self-learning from a book? It's best if you re-read the chapter the exercise is in until you understand what it taught.

Comment: I'm not sure why there have been so many down votes. Also, I don't think the OP is trying to "cheat" - he's just asking for a nudge in the right direction. I've read some good and some terrible text books before now.

Comment: Im not trying to cheat, it's a optional exercise that I am stuck on, thought I would see what I was missing. I could just skip it, but I'd rather learn how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do what it says - put `return` in where `answer` is being used:

```
def ask question
  while (true)
    puts question
    reply = gets.chomp.downcase

    if (reply == 'yes' or reply == 'no')
      if reply == 'yes'
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    else
      puts 'Please answer "yes" or "no".'
    end
  end #while ends here
end
```